# Does Xperia Mini have automatic camera flash?

Tags: camera

Just today I learned that Sony did a nasty trick with Xperia Ray and it features only manual flash.

So I would like to be now super sure how it is with Xperia Mini -- does it have normal automatic flash for camera, or only a manual one as in Ray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an owner of the Mini ST15i, the answer is yes, it does have the automatic flash for camera in which it can be turned off if the need arises.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Btw. does this symbol "ST15i" makes a difference between Mini and Mini Pro, or there are two different "regular" Minis?

Comment: The Xperia Mini Pro has the keyboard, Xperia Mini comes without it. ST15i is the name for the mentioned Xperia Mini. Also, ST15i is the 2011 model code to distinguish from the older model Xperia Mini which was in 2010.